# Is it always a tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If any two compound propositions $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent, then is the proposition formed from their biconditional $P \leftrightarrow Q$ always a tautology?

Comment: Yes: $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent when they have the same truth-value : i.e.both are *True* or both are *False*. But in both case the formula $P \leftrightarrow Q$ will be evaluated to *True*; thus, it is a *tautology*.

Comment: What is your definition of equivalent propositions?

Comment: @Mauro thanks much. Got it!

Comment: @5xum I'll tell you "my" definition. If you think answering a novice's question with another question and answering with a simple yes or no plus a small explanation are equivalent, then any two compound propositions are equivalent.

Comment: @YounisShah What if I told you I asked you a question because I needed you to answer it before I could give you an answer? Also, what if I told you that being sarcastic smart-arse won't get you a lot of friends on this page?

Comment: Then you'd be dead wrong.

Comment: @YounisShah Just a warning: it may happen that you will need the help from this site again, maybe even more than once. If you will be rude to one senior user on each of your questions, you may soon notice that you are getting less and less answers from less and less experienced users...

Comment: Alright. I apologize for my behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; this can be proved using the [deduction theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem).

TFAE.

1. $(P \vdash Q) \wedge (Q \vdash P)$
2. $(\vdash P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (\vdash Q \rightarrow P)$
3. $\vdash (P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow P)$
4. $\vdash (P \leftrightarrow Q)$

Comment: The deduction theorem doesn't require that a $\land$ connective exist.  This proof isn't valid for the subsystem of propositional calculus which only has $\rightarrow$ and ↔ as connectives.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood, sounds interesting. Where does one learn about such subsystems? In particular, does the equivalence still hold in the sublanguage/subtheory generated by $\rightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$?

Comment: @Goblin To start one's study, one could join any known axiom set for the implicational calculus of propositions to any known axiom set for the equivalential calculus under suitable rules of detachment and uniform substitution... such as the pair {CCCpqrCCrpCsp, EEpqEErqEpr} under the rules {C$\alpha$$\beta$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$, {E$\alpha$$\beta$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$ with uniform substitution for variables.  The equivalence will still hold, since the intended semantics are bivalent.  If the truth value "V" of two propositions is equivalent, then V(p)=V(q).  Now...

Comment: The truth value of an equivalence V(p↔q) is equal to V(p)↔V(q).  So, given that the diagonal of the truth table always evaluates to the designated value, then the equivalence here will hold.  And since the semantics are still two-valued for the subsystem I've described, we have that the diagonal of the truth-table evaluates to the designated value "truth", and thus the equivalence holds.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I'll define "equivalence" as meaning that two propositions have the same truth-value.

↔ is defined by this table where $F$ indicates falsity, $T$ indicates truth, and $U$ indicates that the truth-value of a proposition takes on some other value than truth or falsity:

```
↔  F  U  T
F  T  U  F
U  U  U  U
T  F  U  T
```

If $P$ has truth value of $U$, and so does $Q$, then $P$ and $Q$ end up equivalent.  $P$ could come as the compound proposition (a↔b) and $Q$ as the compound proposition (a↔b).  However, ($P$↔$Q$) is not a tautology.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. But I didn't understand your answer. Can you please simplify a bit?

Comment: @YounisShah, note that Doug isn't talking about the usual semantics for propositional logic here. Under the usual, classical semantics, the answer to your question is an emphatic "yes."

Comment: @Goblin what should I learn in order to understand what Doug has answered? Can you point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: @YounisShah, sorry, I do not know much about alternative semantics for the language of propositional logic.

Comment: @Goblin no worries. Cheers.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood can you please help me here?

Comment: @YounisShah Goblin is correct.  If the semantics are bivalent (or equivalently classical), then the answer to your question is an emphatic "yes".  One might consult Merrie Bergmann's book "An Introduction to Many-Valued and Fuzzy Logic" and its references for more on non-classical systems.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood so you mean to say equivalences that hold in classical systems might not hold in fuzzy logic?

Comment: @YounisShah That is true, yes.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Alright. Isn't there a way to combine the two systems such that equivalences hold in both the systems?

Comment: I mean to say can't we "normalize" a many-valued system to a bivalent system?

Comment: @YounisShah There do exist many-valued systems which have the same tautologies as bivalent systems.  See the Bergmann book and the section on Bochvar's 3-valued systems for an example.  Though, there probably is a greater amount of many-valued systems which have different tautologies than bivalent systems.

Comment: Alright. That really helped. Thank you so much for your time. Proost!